# Converting a boolean array into a hexadecimal number

Tags: c#, .net, binary, boolean

Is there an easy way to convert an array of boolean values into 8-bit hexadecimal equivlents? For example, if I have

```
 bool[] BoolArray = new bool[] { true,false,true,true,false,false,false,true };
```

If true values=1 and false values=0 then I'd like a method or function that would convert the above array to 0xB1 (10110001).

Does there exist such a function or method to do this? I am using C#, by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `BitArray` class. Something like this should do it:

```
BitArray arr = new BitArray(BoolArray);
byte[] data = new byte[1];
arr.CopyTo(data, 0);
```

If by "8-bit hexadecimal" you mean the string representation, you can use the `BitConverter` class for that:

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

Comment: This worked, but I forgot to answer it till now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
static int BoolArrayToInt(bool[] arr)
{
    if (arr.Length > 31)
        throw new ApplicationException("too many elements to be converted to a single int");
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        if (arr[i]) val |= 1 << i;
    return val;
}

static string ToHexStr(int i) { return i.ToString("X8"); }
```

*note: an editor remarked that `arr[0]` is the **LSB** but he expected **MSB**. This is an API consideration, if you prefer your LSB to be at `arr[length-1]` just reverse the array before passing to that function.*

Comment: Best answer, which allows non 8bit encodings.

Answer (score -1):

The Binary part can be achieved through this method:

`bool[] boolArray = {true, false, true}` will give **101**:

```
int BoolArrayToInt(bool[] bArray)
{

    char[] caseChar = new char[bArray.Length];

    for(int i = 0; i < bArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (bArray[i] == true)
        {
            caseChar[i] = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            caseChar[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    string caseString = new string(caseChar);
    int caseNum = System.Convert.ToInt32(caseString);
    return caseNum;

}
```