# C# - BitArray to Hex

Tags: c#, .net

I have `BitArray` with differents size and i want to get the conversion in a hex string.
I have tried to convert the `BitArray` to `byte[]`, but it didn't give me the right format. ([Converting a boolean array into a hexadecimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533545/converting-a-boolean-array-into-a-hexadecimal-number))

For exemple, a `BitArray` of 12, and i want the string to be A8C (3 hexa because 12 bits)
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4619295/4928207

Comment: And what if `BitArray` has a size of `13`?

Comment: Coudn't you just trim your result string to the length of `Math.Ceil(BitArray.Length / 4.0)`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `BitArray` are a multiple of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try direct

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bits.Length / 4);

  for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i += 4) {
    int v = (bits[i] ? 8 : 0) | 
            (bits[i + 1] ? 4 : 0) | 
            (bits[i + 2] ? 2 : 0) | 
            (bits[i + 3] ? 1 : 0);

    sb.Append(v.ToString("x1")); // Or "X1"
  }

  String result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented three useful **Extension methods** for BitArray which is capable of doing what you want:

```
    public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(this BitArray bitArray)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling(bitArray.Count / 8.0)];
        bitArray.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        return bytes;
    }

    public static int ConvertToInt32(this BitArray bitArray)
    {
        var bytes = bitArray.ConvertToByteArray();

        int result = 0;

        foreach (var item in bytes)
        {
            result += item;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ConvertToHexadecimal(this BitArray bitArray)
    {
        return bitArray.ConvertToInt32().ToString("X");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution provide at [Converting a boolean array into a hexadecimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533545/converting-a-boolean-array-into-a-hexadecimal-number) is correct.

```
        BitArray arr = new BitArray(new int[] { 12 });
        byte[] data1 = new byte[100];
        arr.CopyTo(data1, 0);
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data1);
```

Comment: This solution is working for BitArray which are multiple of 8. But for 12 it doesn't work

Comment: solved like this: `var data1 = new byte[(arr.Length - 1) / 8 + 1];`