# BitArray(16) to HexString

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a BitArray to a Hex String

My test BitArray is "0000001010000000" and it should return "02 80" in Hex

Tried the following:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(16);
b.Set(7, true);
b.Set(9, true);
```

Then, by examining the BitArray object I created and do get the 640 decimal value that corresponds to that binary string.

But I can't find the way to convert that to Hex.

I'm avoiding working with Byte Array which is a different class.

This works, but it's kind of complicated I'm sure there must be an easier way and I can't understand why I must switch the values.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
b.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
string Retorno = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
string[] auxstr = Retorno.Split('-');
Retorno = auxstr[1] + "-" + auxstr[0];
```

Any advice?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5533572/2030635) SO post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: You could convert it to `byte[]` like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560123/convert-from-bitarray-to-byte) and format the bytes individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, by examining the BitArray object i created and do get the 640 decimal value that corresponds to that binary string.

So you only want to create a string representation of the hexadecimal value? This can be easily done like that:

```
int dec = 640;
string s = Convert.ToString(dec, 16);
```

or even `string s = $"{dec:X}";`

For leading zeros (as you show in your question) the best would be

```
string s = $"{dec:X4}";
```

Note that `640` as hexadecimal is `280` not `208` as you stated in your question.

---

An easy way to get the "value" of your `BitArray` is (for length <= 32):

```
int v = array.OfType<bool>().Select((b, i) => b ? 1 << i : 0).Sum()
```

Comment: Kind of, but i do need to get that decimal number from the BitArray first

Comment: @VyacheslavShcherbakov does the last line of my answer do what you want? Or do you need something for bigger arrays?

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string binary = "0000001010000000";

StringBuilder hexvalue= new StringBuilder(binary.Length / 8 + 1);           

int Len = binary.Length % 8;
if (Len != 0)
{               
     binary = binary.PadLeft(((binary.Length / 8) + 1) * 8, '0');
}

for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
{
     string Bits = binary.Substring(i, 8);
     hexvalue.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", Convert.ToByte(Bits , 2));
}

binary =  hexvalue.ToString();
```

Comment: The specification of the capacity when calling the constructor of `StringBuilder` is unnecessary. Also, some explanation about what this does would probably be very handy for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your bitArray sets and string representation are not the same.

You wrote `0000001010000000` which is actually set like this:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(16);
b.Set(6, true);
b.Set(8, true);
```

But your code:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(16);
b.Set(7, true);
b.Set(9, true);
```

actually produces this set of numbers:

`0000000101000000`

If you want to reproduce Hex `0280` than you should do this:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(16);
b.Set(6, true);
b.Set(8, true);

var @string = String.Concat(b.Cast<bool>().Select(x=> { return x ? '1' : '0'; }));
var result = Convert.ToInt32(@string, 2).ToString("X4");
```

where `result` will have this value `0280`